# Risk free interest and integral setup

Tags: integration, functions, finance

[image: This question is from a past examn]

[image: This is part of the solution given to us]

A very simple question im wondering why we would use an integral for I in the line after the graph?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why you have
$$\int_{I_0}^{I(t)} \frac{dI}I = \int_0^t r(\tilde t)\,d\tilde t$$
as opposed to
$$I=\int_0^t r(\tilde t)\,d \tilde t$$
it's because interest is compounded continuously, in which case the amount of money $I$ in the account changes at a(n interest) rate proportional to $I$, i.e. $\frac{dI}{dt}=rI$. Separate variables, then integrate.